# Entity Framework Core Slow First Time Loading

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, ef-core-2.0

I am dealing with Entity Framework Core DbContext Warm Up time. I have very large DbContext, and I am registering out DbContexes with AddDbContextPool() option, which register DbContext as a singleton and application reuses it.

in an earlier version of EF, to speed up your application startup time following workarrounds are applied: Using a Cached DbModelStore, Generate pre-compiled Views, and/or Generate pre-compiled version of entity framework using NGen to avoid jitting.

However, I dont see any valid way of applying these on Entity Framework Core. I even could not find any other way of avoiding initial start-up / worm-up time of the DbContext.

The worm up time of our application is arround 30+ seconds.

I tried to initialize DbContextes when my application first starts however this doest seems an elegant or event affordable solution.

there is a feature request for compiled views on Entity Framework Core team (Github) however, there is no deadline for this feature.

I need to know if there is any workaround and/or solution which I can apply.

Thank you

Comment: "Worm up time", hilarious error! On topic: why is the warm up time something you care about, this should only happen after start of the server right? Granted this is not great, but once you're up is performance good?

Comment: If I use AddDbContext I am encountering with worm-up time multiple times. But If I use AddDbContextPool the service registration is made as singleton, so services works well. This happends on the first request and I am working on high transactional project. So, First transaction takes 30 seconds. Which is not acceptable.

Comment: It seems like you're not using the right tools for your problem then... maybe you should look into using something like Dapper. EF isn't well renowned for it's great speeds and performance. I don't have enough experience with these kinds of problems to help you more concretely unfortunately.

Comment: Sure this has nothing to do with your web server configuration? When using IIS you can set 'Idle time' to '0' under your application pools settings - different web server might have similar settings.

Comment: I Will take a look at my Web Server configuration. changing Idle Timeout to 0 will definitely help. Lets see

Answer (score 1):

First start is slow because EF configuring table mappings. Most important thing that you can do is to redesign you dbcontext. You must split configurations into different contexts. One context must contains few entities, associated in meaning (as is done in DDD). E.g. UserDbContext (for authorization. Provides users, tokens, personalData...), CustomerDbContext (provides all customer data: customers, contacts, contracts, offers...)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into difficulty with dbContext warm up times as we have one really big dbContext, or shall I say had. To resolve it we now have multiple dbContexts for differing parts of the application. It does come highly recommended.

Then use the old data annotations [NotMapped] property to close off your dbcontexts. [DBContext slow when initially building](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49731496/dbcontext-slow-when-initially-building)